# Clickar un botón y que cambie de fondo otro botón

Tags: java, android

Mi código es el siguiente :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    final int[] Colors1 = {0XFFFFFFFF};
    final int[] Colors2 = {0X00000000};

    int c1 = (int)(Math.random()*1);        //INICIALIZA EL BOTON1 A BLANCO PARA EMPEZAR PARTIDA
    button.setBackgroundColor(0XFF00FFFF); //INICIALIZA EL BOTON1 A BLANCO PARA EMPEZAR PARTIDA



     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        v.setBackgroundColor(0X00FFFFFF);   //CAMBIE DE COLOR
```

//////AQUI ESTA MI DUDA /////

```
        float Button[] = {button2, button3};    

        int c1 = (int)(Math.random()*2);        //INICIALIZA EL BOTON1 A BLANCO PARA EMPEZAR PARTIDA
        v.setBackgroundColor(c1[0XFF00FFFF]);
```

/////AQUI ESTA MI DUDA//////

```
     button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int c = (int)(Math.random()*2);
                v.setBackgroundColor(Colors[c]);
            }
        });

button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int c = (int)(Math.random()*2);
                v.setBackgroundColor(Colors[c]);
            }
        });
     }
```

Como bien he indicado el problema es que dentro de `onClick` del primer botón quiero que, al pinchar el boton 1, se me cambie de color ese mismo ( está PUESTO Y FUNCIONA) pero además quiero ( Y NO ME SALE Y ESTA INDICADO EN EL CODIGO) que aleatoriamente seleccione el boton 2 o boton 3 y LE CAMBIE el fondo. ¿ Para qué? Pues para volver a ir al boton y volver a hacer lo mismo y asi...

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza la función `random` dentro de una función privada con un `switch` para seleccionar un botón aleatorio.

```
private void cambiaColorBoton(int idBotonActual) {

    int N = 3; //Pongo 3 porqué sólo tienes 3 botones definidos, modifica N por el número total de botones que tengas y ya.
    final Random rand = new Random();
    int botonRandomID = rand.nextInt(N) + 1; //Obtienes un valor entre 1 y N
    while (botonRandomID == idBotonActual) botonRandomID = rand.nextInt(N) + 1;
    //Seleccionamos el color para no repetir código antes del switch
    int c = (int)(Math.random()*2);

    //Según el resultado del random seleccionamos el botón:
    switch(botonRandomID ) {
        case 1:
            button.setBackgroundColor(Colors[c]);
            break;
        case 2:
            button2.setBackgroundColor(Colors[c]);
            break;
        case 2:
            button3.setBackgroundColor(Colors[c]);
            break;
        default:
            button.setBackgroundColor(Colors[c]);
    }

}
```

Esta función que he nombrado `cambiaColorBoton` llámala des de todos los `OnClick()` y en el mismo onclick inicializa el botón a blanco:

```
//Boton 1
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    v.setBackgroundColor(0XFF00FFFF);
    cambiaColorBoton(1);
}

//Boton 2
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    v.setBackgroundColor(0XFF00FFFF);
    cambiaColorBoton(2);
}

//Boton 3
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    v.setBackgroundColor(0XFF00FFFF);
    cambiaColorBoton(3);
}
```

Comment: Hola Miquel. Si reproduces el código que me has pasado con 3 botones que pongas en tu xml, comprobarás que por ejemplo, pinchas el primero pero no se enciende sí o sí alguno de los otros 2 botones, hay veces que sí y otras que no, lo que yo decía era: Tienes 3 botones, 1 con fondo blanco (por ejemplo) y los otros 2 negro. Cuando pinches en el de fondo blanco se vuelva negro y SÍ O SÍ uno de los otros dos se vuelva blanco. Sabes a lo que me refiero? Siempre tiene que haber 1 en blanco y 2 en negro.

Comment: @RfMvs Tienes razón, eso es simple de hacer simplemente con el random evitando el botón que YA está encendido. Dame unos minutos y te actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: Actualziado! Ahora el mismo botón que llama no se puede encender y 100% tiene que ser otro :)

Comment: Qué parámetro le has metido a cambiaColorBoton en onClick? Una vez me respondas esto y miraré código e investigaré y si no me sale volveré a comentar y muchas gracias :)

Comment: Le he metido 0 , y ya está, voy a investigar y te comento! muchas gracias, estamos en contacto.

Comment: Es el ID del botón actual! 1,2 o 3 en este caso.. :) Lo pongo más específico.

Comment: Tienes algun metodo para ponerme en contacto contigo tipo skype para no hacer esto un chat?

Comment: Tenemos un chat para la comunidad dónde podemos hablar (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) o crear un chat específico temporal para esta pregunta [chat]

Comment: No tengo suficiente reputacion para abrir chat, agregame a skype por favor si no te importa y hablamos cuando puedas,infinitas gracias: rafaespada3

Comment: Al final me ha salido, he puesto algo más sencillo.. He puesto en cada case lo siguiente:  Que si pulso se quite el color y el resto se pongan del color del fondo, dando así la impresión de que cambian de color justo cuando presiono, algo menos sofisticado pero eficaz que es lo que importa, es decir... dentro de cada case he puesto 6 lineas, una para cada boton(habia hecho la prueba con 6) si case 1 pues 1 blanco y el resto negro y asi con todos los case, gracias por tu aportacion pues sin tu ayuda no lo habria logrado, me faltaba saber los switch